# Why did Bauria throw the drugs into the well?

Tags: plot-explanation, udta-punjab

In *Udta Punjab*, why did Bauria throw the drugs into the well? Those drugs were worth a fortune and Bauria could become very rich. She took all the trouble to gather the address of Drugs buyer and went there hiding the drugs from Police. So what happened that she suddenly panicked and threw away all the drugs into the well water?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You answered it yourself:

> she panicked.

Bauria wanted to be a national level hockey player but her dream shattered and now she is stuck in unsatisfied life and during that time she dot the packet of drug and though it's her chance of fortune. During the song "Da Da Dasse" we can see how scarred she is during her travel and also her walk and get anxious about every staring eyes. Then  she started running and the gang spotted her and shouted for her to stop and she got more scarred and the end u getting panicked and throw it all in the well.